# Getting an Error in starting gunicorn on ubuntu virtual machine on azure

Tags: python-3.x, django, nginx, cloud, gunicorn

when i run `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` i get this

```
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-01-24 20:00:09 UTC; 25min ago
TriggeredBy: ● gunicorn.socket
  Process: 6889 ExecStart=/home/yawar/django_folder/myenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - -- workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock route_pro.wsgi:application (code=exited, status>
 Main PID: 6889 (code=exited, status=4)

Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6889]: [2022-01-24 20:00:09 +0000] [6889] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6889]: [2022-01-24 20:00:09 +0000] [6889] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/run/gunicorn.sock (6889)
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6889]: [2022-01-24 20:00:09 +0000] [6889] [INFO] Using worker: sync
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6891]: [2022-01-24 20:00:09 +0000] [6891] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 6891
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6891]: Failed to find attribute 'application' in 'workers'.
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6891]: [2022-01-24 20:00:09 +0000] [6891] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 6891)
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6889]: [2022-01-24 20:00:09 +0000] [6889] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO gunicorn[6889]: [2022-01-24 20:00:09 +0000] [6889] [INFO] Reason: App failed to load.
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION
Jan 24 20:00:09 XPO systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
lines 1-17/17 (END)
```

what could I be doing wrong , and before that it was throwing a error like `no module named workers found` so i ran `pip3 install workers` and now i get the new error, can anyone help?

Comment: Does the user you're running as have permission on `/run/gunicorn.sock` as you're getting an error for permission: `Main process exited, code=exited, status=4/NOPERMISSION`

Comment: yes i have done ```sudo chown yawar:www-data run```